# Untraceable exception in java applet

Tags: java, logging, javafx, applet

I'm having some problems tracing the reason that I can't load a java(fx) applet.

The java plugin console for the browser has always been my sole source of information for problem solving. The reason it isn't much help at the moment is that the applet starts to load, downloading the jar files and outputting a percentage to the console along with the occasional statement to say it's on the next jar file. At some point in time (different percentages each time) the console just closes unexpectedly and the applet stops loading. I know this isn't much to go on but I was wondering if there was any way that the output from the console could be stored to a file on the local machine. To debug this particular problem, changing security permissions temporarily would be acceptable.

The problem has occured on every pc i've tried, however if I keep refreshing after failure it seems to cache the jar files previously downloaded and thus get further through the loading process until it eventually works. My issue now is that on a particular customers network refreshing does not resolve the issue. I thought it may be a permissions issue writing to disk but I've tried an administrator account and still no luck. I've also tried a variety of browsers. It might also be worth noting that they go through a proxy server - when the applet tries to load it asks for the credentials for logging on to the proxy which seems to authorise fine.

If anyone has a suggestion on what I could try it would be gratefully received.

Thanks,

James

Comment: "a suggestion on what I could try.."  Try launching it using Java Web Start (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being some JS code that was making calls to the applet before the applet had initialised.

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1. You should be able to get a stack trace through the applet console viewer (which runs in the system tray on PC's) and if you open that up it will show you your stack trace for debugging.
2. Can you reproduce this problem using the Java Applet Viewer tool?  This will allow you to write unit tests, and debug much more easily.

Comment: Thanks for your response Will. I will definitely give the applet viewer a go, sounds very promising since I imagine the stack trace will come out on the windows command prompt/bash terminal. With respect to point 1, this is the console I was referring to when I mentioned 'the console just closes' preventing me to view any stack trace. I've even tried recording the screen to see it's last output before closing.

Answer (score 1):

I forget where it is, but somewhere in the java control panel (one of the options under the advanced tab I believe) there's an option to turn on logging.  This will log all output to the java console to a file as well.  I've used this when trying to debug issues similar to this.

There's some info here on where the files will appear:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/tracing_logging.html